# How to iterate over an Arraylist in expression language?

Tags: jsp, el

In my application on inspecting the model bean looks something like this,

```
mybeanobj=bean
->strName
->strSirname
->intAge
->arrListAddress
  ->[0]=addBean
     propa
     propb
     propc
  ->[1]=addBean
     propa
     propb
     propc
  ->[2]=addBean
     propa
     propb
     propc
->strReligion
```

Now in my jsp i want access the child's and subchild's of the property 'arrListAddress' using expression Language. Please help me with the code.
"${mybeanobj.strName}",$"{mybeanobj.strSirname}" etc are working fine. Please tell me how to access the arraylist.

Comment: <c:forEach var="mylist" items="${mybeanobj.arrListAddress}">  Tried with this but i know this will not fetch me the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work ,

```
<c:forEach var="mylist" items="Name of your list which you are passing in your servlet">
<c:out value="${mylist.arrListAddress}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

it will work if youare setting the values properly at server side

Hope this helps !!

Comment: The list is a property of the bean object,i dnt have direct access to it  and i have shown what my bean looks like,therefore it i guess the values are set properly.

Comment: so you need to iterate a list inside a list . Am i correct ?

Comment: The problem i am facing here is that the arraylist is linked to another bean. In my jsp the command name is given that of the parent bean and therefore the properties of the arraylist are not found in the scope.